# InternalOAuthError when using nodejs passport to integration third party platform

Tags: node.js, facebook, http, ssl, oauth

I want to use passport(using paasport-facebook and qq) to authenticate user. But meeting the following error:
when I using facebook auth:

```
error when auth: { [InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain access token]
name: 'InternalOAuthError',
message: 'Failed to obtain access token',
oauthError: [Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames] }
```

when I using qq auth,I got this:

```
name: 'InternalOAuthError',
message: 'failed to obtain access token',
oauthError: [Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED] }
```

Here is my /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       www.siyee.org
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

because the auth callback must be a domain, so I changed the hosts on my development environment to match the callback settings on the facebook server.It's not smart but can take effect.Any better idea?

I think the problem is in my hosts setting or certificate, but I don't know how to fix it, any kind of help would be great!

Comment: Did you advance on this one? I am facing a similar issue with passport-google `message: failed to fetch user profile, oauthError insufficient permission`

Answer (score 1):

First I had to specify access to `userinfo` and only then - other necessary services.

```
    scope: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'
    ]
```